# Android: 'getViewId()' from MotionEvent in override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it is possible to get the id of a view which was clicked/touched, by overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent` Method?! So I need it like pEvent.getClickedViewId(). I m just having some weird UI-bahaviours and I guess it's because some layouts are overlapping. That's why I want to check, which view is in foreground with the TouchEvent...

```
 @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent pEvent) {

    Log.d("TOUCH EVENT","getCLickedViewid?!?!" );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily get the view at that point, as dispatchTouchEvent is fired before it has been dispatched to any view. You'd have to figure out which view would handle the event yourself.

A more common way is to add touch listeners via the view.setOnTouchListener() method, which will get the view passed in to the handler. But if this works in your case, as by this point the event has been dispatched, I'm not sure.